# How to give a "return" value?

Tags: sensor, temperature

I have a circuit. This is what it looks like, made in Proteus.

[image]

I’m trying to simulate temperature sensor. This is when the simulation is started. When the sim is ended, of course the blue LED is turned of. Also there is potentiometer, which seems make the circuit works when the potentiometer is 5% of 10 kΩ which is 500 Ω. When it touches 6%, the circuit is turned off. Therefore, the blue LED is turned off.

My only question is, how do I get some "return" value from the electric current around this blue LED. Whether it's turned on or off, what component, IC, or anything else that could tell me, that there is electric current happen. Is it something like transistor or comparator?

I’m also trying to do this with IR sensors.

Comment: why do you have two LEDs doing the same thing?

Comment: dunno. im just following the tutorial on youtube. the green LED is the one which made in the vid, and the blue one is the LED added by myself. could it bring some errors and inefficiency in my circuit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You look at pin 1 of U4A. If it's high, the circuit is on. If it's low, then it's off.